# grep for words containing both uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: grep, uppercase, lowercase

I'm converting a bunch of (Progress) programs for use on linux (previously used on Windows) and I'm looking for a way to grep for program names with both uppercase and lowercase letters, such as "skip_xref.I" or "NO_dt2.i". 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

this regexshould help:

```
 [a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]
```

If you want to work with grep:

```
grep '[a-z].*[A-Z]\|[A-Z].*[a-z]'
```

or

```
grep -E '[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]'
```

Comment: I suggest to prefix grep with `LANG=C ` because it doesn't work with my default `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. And what if I want to limit the grep to words that contain a . (dot) ? the names I am looking for typically end with a dot followed by a single character: Program.I or aFileName.p

Comment: @Kent with the command like you suggested I get all lines in all programs as a result.

Comment: @Mark you didn't use the pattern with dots, did you? `[a-z].*.......` I meant the pattern in answer.

Comment: @Kent no i used it like this: grep '[.].$'| grep -E '[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]' * | more

Comment: @Mark what is the `*` before your last pipe? you should do: `grep '..' inputFile(s) |grep` or `yourProgram|grep|grep`

Comment: @Kent I want to search all files in the folder I am currently in that is why I used the * .  When I add it at the end of the first grep, which is what I should have done, it returns the same result which seems to be all lines that contain an all uppercase word

Comment: @Mark the first grep finds out the lines with `[.].$` then pipe this result to the 2nd grep. I don't see how can you get all uppercase words. It would be nice if you can add some example in your question, also what/how have you done with grep(s). **Wait** `grep 'pattern' *` will search the content of all files instead of the filename, I hope you knew it. Do a quick test with `ls -1|grep ..|grep ..`

Comment: Below is the content of a test file I wrote:/* a testprogram fro grepping*/
{us/mf/mfdtitle.i "a"}

{set_xref.I}
{pxmaint.i}
{PXMSG.i &ERRORLEVEL=3 &MSGNUM=1}
{gprun.i ""myProgram.p""}
/*this is a comment sosomt.p*/
sosomt.p
hhHHhh.hhH
EINDE
when I run grep '[.].$' testprogram.p | grep -E '[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]' | more    
there is no output at all where as I would have expected (or want to have)
{set_xref.I}
{gprun.i ""myProgram.p""}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not answering the ambiguous question, but you can use the case-insensitive flag of grep `-i`,

e.g. `docker help build | grep -i dockerfile` it will still find "Dockerfile".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls -l |grep 'pattern1\|pattern2'`
(assuming you are in a dir where you want to search the programs)

Do a web search to read more on general `regex` basics to get the pattern you need.

Answer (score 0):

To find filename you can't use grep, you're gonna need to use find.

You can use a regex in find but then you need to match the whole path. Starting the match with `.*/\` will solve the problem so it's not a big deal.

Then:

```
find . -regex ".*/.*[a-z]+.*[A-Z]+*.*"
```

will match filename who have at least one lowercase character followed by one uppercase character.

If you use group to have this pattern and also the opposite (switching lowercase and uppercase), you should get all matches:

```
find . -regex ".*/\(\(.*[a-z]+.*[A-Z]+\)\|\(.*[A-Z]+.*[a-z]+\)\).*"
```

Comment: I definitely want to use a grep. I want to search through all files in a certain folder for text which might be a program name and consists of both lower case and upper case letters